# Styling table generated by PHP foreach with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to style a `<tr id="options">` generated by a `PHP` `foreach()` with jQuery, but everything I've tried only selects the first one, leaving the others intact. What can I do this? Simple example:

CSS:

```
td {border:1px solid black}
```

TABLE:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>DATE</td>
  <td>EXAM TITLE</td>
  <td>EXAM CODE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>TODAY</td>
  <td>RANDOM</td>
  <td>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BUTTON</td>
  <td>BUTTON</td>
  <td>BUTTON</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=3 id="options">
</tr>
```

I have tried this jQuery code (among other):

```
$("table").find("#options").each(function(){
  $(this).css("border","0px");
});
```

It only styles my first `<td id="options">`. How can I get all of them?
Sorry if it is a stupid question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: use class `<td class="options"></td>`

Comment: because you are using ID use class. **ID should be unique**

Comment: "id" is meant to be used only once as a unique identifier. Use "class" instead

Comment: Why do you want to add style rules by means of javascript (jquery)? Why not simply load a static css file which is the normal way?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I knew it was a simple thing, I just couldn't get my head around it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ arkascha I have elements after that <tr> that will be displayed onclick, that's why I use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert `id` to `class`like:- `<td class="options">..</td>`

and then you can use(Use Either-one)

CSS (standered way):-

```
td.options {border:1px solid black}
```

Or jQuery(try to avoid as much as possible):-

```
$('.options').css("border","1px solid black"); // no need of each
```

Example (both at same time):-

```js
 $('.options').css("font-size","21px");
```

```css
td.options {border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="options">DATE</td>
  <td class="options">EXAM TITLE</td>
  <td class="options">EXAM CODE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="options">TODAY</td>
  <td class="options">RANDOM</td>
  <td class="options">123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="options">BUTTON</td>
  <td class="options">BUTTON</td>
  <td class="options">BUTTON</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ciprian C  glad to help you